# Difference between mysql essential and community version

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project and I was advised to install MySQL essential version for my application but when I searched on the web, I found the community version of MySQL from MySQL official website but not the essential. It also seem to me that the essential version has been moved to their archive.

What is the main difference? 
Is the essential version now the community version?

I already know that both are the free version of MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the essential version is a developer's installation (Drivers, tools, etc) where the community edition is just the server itself.